# Mac Android SDK - (installed) gray out

Tags: android, macos, sdk

I install Android Studio on Mac. 
At the Android Studio SDK Component Setup page, Android SDK - (installed) gray out. 
So I downloaded the sdk tools folder and try to add the path at the SDK Location, but it always says SDK tools directory is missing.
[image]
the sdkmanager is not working when i ran it.

and when i look into the android studio application, there's no sdk inside.

Comment: Do you see anything at `/Users/<username>/Library/Android/sdk`?

Comment: @HBB20 I even did not see that folder in my /Users/username/Library/, that is so wired